# 24 hour format for the actual time?

Tags: php, date, datetime, time, timezone

I would like to get the actual date + time, and convert it (the time) to a 24 hour format (e.g: `15/04/2017 13:32:02`)

My current code is :

```
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Magadan");
$date = date("d/m/Y h:i:s");
echo $date;
```

That display :

```
15/04/2017 01:32:02
```

Thanks.

Comment: The php documentation has this information http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php. Use date("d/m/Y H:i:s");

Comment: Oh, so simple finally, thanks :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put the h capital for 24 hour format    date("d/m/Y H:i:s");

Answer (score 1):

Finally, to change to a 24 hour format we only have to change the H of the hour to a MAJ/CAPS.

```
$date = date("d/m/Y H:i:s");
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Answer (score 0):

convert **(h:i:s)** to **(H:i:s)** . that's worked for me